# QEvent::FocusOut with error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

Tags: c++, qt, enums

I'm using the enum QEvent::Type in an eventFilter(). Code looks like this:

```
#include <QEvent>
...
bool myClass::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) {
    if (evnet->type() == QEvent::FocusOut) {                 // first "if"
    // if (event->type() == static_cast<QEvent::Type>(9)) {  // second "if"
        // Do something...
    }
    retrun QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

With the first "if", I got a compile error:

```
myfile.cpp: In member function 'virtual bool myClass::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)':
myfile.cpp:66: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
myfile.cpp:66: error: expected ')' before numeric constant.
Compile myfile.cpp failed
```

However, if I changed to the second "if" which I commented out (9 is the integer for FocusOut in Event::Type enum), it compiles.

On the other hand, with the first "if", I also tried with some other types, strange enough, some of them compile(ActionAdded, Close...), some do not(FocusIn, FocusOut...).

I searched a little on the web and it seems to be related with the OS but I didn't really figure it out. I'm using RHEL5.8. Anybody knows what is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: which Qt version? which compiler? please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Qt 4.8.5 (64 bit).   gcc version 4.1.2

Comment: how about upgrading to at least a recent gcc version?

Comment: Try adding a check to see if `#ifdef FocusOut`

Comment: @m.s. I changed to version 4.4.5 and it's the same problem. Since this is a small piece of code inside a big project, I need other code to compile and 4.4.5 is the latest one I can use in the system.

Comment: @aschepler, tried and it seems FocusOut is already defined.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help and I figured it out.
FocusOut is defined as macro somewhere else in the included files, where I don't have control. I have to undefine it in my file to compile. Just added this after the includes:

#ifdef FocusOut
#undef FocusOut
#endif